# Batch file running 1 of 2 commands

Tags: batch-file, echo

I have a small batch file running at bootup to keep alive 2 HD's from sleeping. Here it is -

```
@echo off
:loop
echo test > v:\hdalivetest1.txt
echo test > d:\hdalivetest2.txt
TIMEOUT /T 1500 /NOBREAK
goto loop
```

The first echo line is running good. The second echo is not executed. I don't know why. If I run this batch file after windows totally boots, both echo's are executed.

Answer (score 0):

Had to add it to task scheduler and now it works fine. I remembered I had to do this for other programs many years ago.